# Set the Height of Plot Shape

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

In trading view pine script, how to set the height of plot shape, which 30% smaller of the 1st/3rd plot ?

> plotshape(bearishStar, style = shape.triangledown, location =
> location.abovebar, color = red, size = size.small)

As refer here [from rmunoz](https://www.tradingview.com/script/BL8j8idt-Evening-Morning-Star-Pattern/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot specifically adjust height of a shape. What you can do is set different `size`s for it.

Possible values are: `size.auto`, `size.tiny`, `size.small`, `size.normal`, `size.large`, `size.huge`.